# HTML and CSS text and sidebar not working withe achother

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to stack some text over a search bar and I cant seem to get the code to work. I am trying to go for a design like this site but without the image. When I run my code the text and search work fine but they are next to each other and I can't see the top of the search bar. Please help.

site = https://emulatoros.github.io/

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
        <style>
    html, body { height: 100% }

    body {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }

    .container {
      max-width: 500px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 50px;
      background-color: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06), 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.02);
    }

    .background {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-color: #000000;
      z-index: -1;
    }

    h1 {
      font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
      font-size: clamp(3rem, 10vw, 10rem);
      color: white;
      padding: 0rem clamp(1rem, 2vw, 3rem);
      border-radius: clamp(0.4rem, 0.75vw, 1rem);
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .li {
      display: inline-block;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .gameimg {
      list-style: none; 
      width: 100%;
      height: 265px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }

    #mySearch {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      list-style: none;
      overflow-y: center;
      overflow:scroll;
      width: 35%;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 11px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    #myMenu {
      list-style: none;
    }
  
    .game {
      float: left;
      list-style: none;
      width: 200px;
      height: 310px;
      border-radius: 8px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 1px solid white;
      display: block;
      margin-right: 35px;
      margin-left: 35px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .game:hover {
      border: 1px solid white;
    }

    .gameinfo {
      list-style: none;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      color: white;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 35px;
    }

    .container {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      list-style: none; 
      padding: 20px;
    }

    .box {
      list-style: none; 
      margin: auto;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 400px;
    }

  </style>

<body>
    <h1 data-value="GAMES">GAMES</h1>

    <div class="overlay-content">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search" id="mySearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search.." title="Type in a category"></input>
        <ul scrolling="auto" id="myMenu">
            <li><div class="game" onclick="goto(),acilspace()"><img src="" class="gameimg"><a onclick="" class="gameinfo">Acilspace</a></div></li>
            <li><div class="game" onclick="goto(),astriods()"><img src="" class="gameimg"><a onclick="" class="gameinfo">Astriods</a></div></li>
            <li><div class="game" onclick="goto(),vex5()"><img src="" class="gameimg"><a onclick="" class="gameinfo">Vex 5</a></div></li>
            <li><div class="game" onclick=""><img src="" class="gameimg"><a onclick="" class="gameinfo">c</a></div></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>

<canvas class="background"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particlesjs/2.2.2/particles.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var particles = Particles.init({
        selector: '.background',
      sizeVariations: 3,
      color: ['#949398', '#674ea7'],
      connectParticles: true
    });

function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("mySearch");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myMenu");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
    
    const letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

let interval = null;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
  const targetValue = h1.dataset.value;
  let iteration = 0;
  
  clearInterval(interval);
  
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    h1.innerText = h1.innerText
      .split("")
      .map((letter, index) => {
        if(index < iteration) {
          return targetValue[index];
        }
      
        return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)]
      })
      .join("");
    
    if(iteration >= targetValue.length){ 
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    
    iteration += 1 / 3;
  }, 75);
});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your some css

```
body {
    /* deleted display flex */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

 .background {
    /* positifon absolute changed fixed */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000000;
  z-index: -1;
}


#mySearch {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      list-style: none;
      overflow-y: center;
      overflow:scroll;
      width: 35%;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 11px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      /* I added these */
      border-radius: 1rem;
      outline: none;
      background-color: rgba(19, 19, 19, 0.301);
      color: white;

    }
```

Comment: this code works but now the games text does not do its cycle and the background does not work

Comment: I will look for you